# How to create content section in xcart?

Tags: x-cart

How we can create content section in xcart like we create in wordpress via widget ? is there any option like this ? i want to make home page with 4 section with image content and link them to particular page .

Comment: Have you tried https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Banner_System ?   http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/admin/banner_system.php

Answer (score 0):

This differs depending on X-Cart version. There are two major versions now: X-Cart 4 and X-Cart 5. They are very different and in order to give you any advice it is better to now what X-Cart version you are using.

Comment: Hi thanks for videos links but i am not looking for that.
My xcart version is 4.7.7 . I want to add three section on home page with text and image and link them to another pages. This task i can easily do with wordpress widget , is there any option in xcart like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Alex Mulin is right, it's kinda difficult to answer your question without such specific info as your X-Cart version.  Yet I'll try to. In both cases the webmaster mode can help you do the trick. See video tutorials below.

Webmaster mode in X-Cart 4 :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QrpH4cQGpE

Webmaster mode in X-Cart 5:
http://devs.x-cart.com/en/webinars_and_video_tutorials/using_webmaster_mode_in_x-cart_5.html

If they don't work for you for some reason, try to ask the same question but be a bit more specific, or at least provide the store URL and I will be able to check the version.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is skin-dependent and each skin has its own sections.
In order to find the files that you need to edit, go to `Admin Panel>Settings>General Settings>Enable debugging console` and check its box.

When checked, if you open your store, it opens a popup that that shows you the smarty templates loaded (make sure your browser does not block popups).

You can then change the smarty template files in order to add whatever you want. If you are not familiar with them, they are basically extended HTML files with some basic commands (`if/for/etc.`) and you can get stuff from PHP files in them as well. You can use xcart webmaster mode to edit those files too as mentioned by other answers.

This video can also be useful for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vN__DZrNrRM (X-Cart - Storefront Design and Layout)

And here's some XCart documentation on how to customize store front and skins:

http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Customizing_storefront

http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Editing_Skin_Files